# Passing data from one screen to another React-native

Tags: react-native, parameter-passing, screen

I'm trying to pass data from one screen to another.

My problem is that the first screen goes to a calendar, when I've finished to put the dates in the calendar, I submit and go back to the first screen, the problem is that the first screen doesn't reload when I go back to it, so the data is not loaded, I think.

First screen : "Mytrips" = I click and go to Calendar

Calendar : I send the 2 datas I need with onPress

```
  <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.touchable2}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MyTrips",
      {selectedStartDate: selectedStartDate, 
       selectedEndDate: selectedEndDate })}
  ></TouchableOpacity>
```

So now, I go back to MyTrips and I set up the data recovery in the state :

```
this.state = {
      selectedStartDate: props.navigation.state.params && props.navigation.state.params.selectedStartDate
        ? props.navigation.state.params.selectedStartDate
        : "",
      selectedEndDate: props.navigation.state.params && props.navigation.state.params.selectedEndDate
        ? props.navigation.state.params.selectedEndDate
        : "",
```

and I want to display it in the screen :

```
<Text>{this.state.selectedStartDate}{this.state.selectedEndDate}</Text>
```

But, there is nothing displayed. I think that it's because when I go back to the first screen, the state is not updated with the data I passed.
Is anyone that can help me ? I think I'm close to get it work but ... I miss something. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, this happens bacause `this.state.selectedStartDate` and `this.state.selectedEndDate` will be not updated when `Calendar` component changes `selectedStartDate` and `selectedEndDate`. In `this.state = {...` you are just copying props into state on first component loading. To update state with new values I suggest you to use `componentDidUpdate` in `MyTrips` component. Something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   // here you could write: 
   // if (prevProps !== this.props) {
   //     this.setState with this.props
   // }
}
```

Comment: oh, thank you for answering I think I get it. I'm gonna try it, I think I have to modify something, for now it returns "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prevProps.navigation.state.params.selectedStartDate')"

Comment: Ciao, sorry. I update my answer inserting a more generical code. This answer it's just to give you an idea on how to update your component using `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me, I'm gonna check it and make some tests.